# linux mounted filesystem consumes space on host

Tags: linux, filesystems

NOTE: I have reinstalled my system and am setting up a caching system instead so I no longer have this problem

I have a 128GB root partition on an SSD, with a 1TB partition on an HDD mounted at /data (both ext4).
my problem is that when the total combined used space on both devices exceeds the 128GB SSD, everything stops working and says something like `can not write to file, no space on device`.

My question is:
is this intended behavior, and is there a way of mitigating the problem?

---

EDIT: here are the outputs of some commands:

```
$ fstab

/dev/sda2   /       ext4    rw,relatime,data=ordered    0 1
/dev/sda1   /boot   vfat    rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro   0 2
/dev/sda3   none    swap    defaults,pri=-2 0 0
/dev/sdb1   /data   ext4    rw,relatime 0 0

$ df -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
dev             3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
run             3.9G  1.3M  3.9G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       109G   20G   84G  19% /
tmpfs           3.9G   55M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           3.9G   64K  3.9G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1       549M   55M  494M  11% /boot
tmpfs           785M   16K  785M   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       473G   79G  370G  18% /data

$ fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: HGST HTS721010A9
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 797F206A-D221-4C61-AF5B-681616314AEA

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1008842751 1008840704 481.1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb2  1008842752 1953523711  944680960 450.5G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sda: 119.2 GiB, 128035676160 bytes, 250069680 sectors
Disk model: LITEON CV8-8E128
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: F404C915-5177-0045-A1CD-A829CA164447

Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1128447   1126400   550M EFI System
/dev/sda2    1128448 233248767 232120320 110.7G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3  233248768 250069646  16820879     8G Linux swap

$ mount | grep /dev/sd

/dev/sda2 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sdb1 on /data type ext4 (rw,relatime)

$ dmesg | grep sdb1

[    1.787574]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2
[    3.238530] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  446.617492] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)

// NOTE: sdb1 was mounted in fstab (3) then unmounted and remounted manually (446)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Comment: @jww oops sorry, should the question be migrated then? Where should I have posted it,

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com . (Next time) . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have mounted the SSD disk which is only 128 GB.
Also you can't mount 2 block devices on same path in your filesystem unless you use LVM or software raid 0 for combining both disk size in a single block device.
Also I won't recommend doing above for SSD and HDD disks together (you will not use benefits of SSD)

if you need farther assistance, please post the output of `df -h` and `fdisk -l`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have created a directory /data as your mount point, but the filesystem is not actually mounted to it. In that case, all data will go to your "parent" file system.

This is a very common pitfall. You don't get any obvious notification that the mount failed, but all your data goes to the wrong place. You run out of space quickly.

You need to find out why mounting failed. Things you could try:

```
mount
```

to list all the devices actually mounted.

```
df -h
```

to see the free space on all your devices. /data should be there.

```
dmesg | grep sdb1
```

to see if there are errors concerning sdb1 in the system log.

Also, try mounting manually with `mount /data` to see if there are any errors when mounting.

Comment: sdb1 is definitely mounted, I have added the output of the requested commands to my question. thank you :)

Comment: Hm, looks all good. You should be able to write 370GB to /data